# No function when click on second Push Notification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have some problems about Push Notification below.
When I receive 2 Push Notification. I click on one Push Notification, it work well(Go to ActivityA)
But I click on a rest Push, I see that just close the second push but without function.
Here's my code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    long[] vibrate = {1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000};
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_push_notification)
            .setContentTitle(this.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(alert)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(vibrate)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    Log.i("gcm","gcm alert = " + alert);

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagePush,R.drawable.ic_push_notification);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.titlePush, this.getString(R.string.app_name));
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textPush, alert);

    notificationBuilder.setContent(contentView);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(commentId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

If You have any idea to resolve this issue, please share for me.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you provide the error logs? It will help us solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, the seems this issue have been fixed by change PendingIntent same as :

`int uniqueInt = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, uniqueInt, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

Please see more [here](http://alvinalexander.com/source-code/android/android-how-attach-extra-intent-pendingintent-notification-solution-example)